# Javascript Changing a Bound Value

Tags: javascript

This function is designed to report and increment the total (counter) for each specific obstacle.

```
function warningMaker( obstacle ){ 
      var count =  0;
      return function ( number, location ) {
        count++;
        alert("Beware! There have been " +
              obstacle +
              " sightings in the Cove today!\n" +
              number +
              " " +
              obstacle +
              "(s) spotted at the " +
              location +
              "!\nThis is Alert #" + count + " today for " + obstacle + " danger."
             );
      };
    }
```

Now if I call the function by saying for example,

```
warningMaker("obstacleName1")(2,"locationName");   ===counter 1
warningMaker("obstacleName1")(2,"locationName");   ===counter still 1
```

But if I call it this way,

```
var obstacle1Maker = warningMaker("obstacleName1");
var obstacle2Maker = warningMaker("obstacleName2");
obstacle1Maker(2,"MiddleEarth");
obstacle1Maker(2,"Hogwarts");
obstacle2Maker(3,"Narnia");
```

### The counter is incremented for every specific obstacle, how is this possible? I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to grasp the concepts behind things like this.

Comment: closure is the answer to your question... every time you call warningMaker function, a new local variable count gets initialized and returned function gets a reference to that variable through closure. So, if you call same returned function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Two different closures hold two different counters. You want sth like this:

```
var obstacles={};
function warningMaker( obstacle ){ 
  var obstacles[obstacle] =  obstacles[obstacle]||0;
  return function ( number, location ) {
    obstacles[obstacle]++;
    alert("Beware! There have been " +
          obstacle +
          " sightings in the Cove today!\n" +
          number +
          " " +
          obstacle +
          "(s) spotted at the " +
          location +
          "!\nThis is Alert #" + obstacles[obstacle] + " today for " + obstacle + " danger."
         );
  };
}
```

Im storing all counts in a global object. Its therefore not dependent on closures etc...

*Why your code doesnt work as expected:*

```
warningMaker("obstacleName1");
```

This assembles a new function context ( function + closure ). It happens when you move a function out of its scope ( variable surrounding ). The function can still access it, as its bound to them ( called closure). So if you call that twice, you will create two different contexts with two different *count* variables...